# Regex: Group all blocks of strings starting with a given character

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have in javascript a text like

```
some text
- list
- list
- list
more text
- another list
- another list
- another list
```

How can I match all the lines that starts with the character `-` until a line doesn't start with that character?
For example, given the text above I need to match the two groups

```
- list
- list
- list
```

and

```
- another list
- another list
- another list
```

I tried with the regex `/^(-.*\n-.*|$)/gm`, but works only if the list contains an even number of elements, while I need it to work for an arbitrary number of elements.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^-.*(?:\n-.*)*` See https://regex101.com/r/amsfMj/1

Comment: Why using regex? I would just loop over the lines and collect lines that start with a certain character until a line is hit without the starting character. This is way easier to understand later.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Please post a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you only match 2 times a hyphen (an even number) and you are not repeating that match.

You could match a single line starting with a hyphen, and then optionally repeat following lines staring with a newline and a hyphen.

```
^-.*(?:\n-.*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/amsfMj/1)

---

A bit more extensive pattern making use of a capture group:

```
^[^-\s].*\n(-\s+[^\s-].*(?:\n-\s+[^\s-].*)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- a leading text on the previous line that does not start with a hyphen
- a whitespace character after each leading `-`
- at least a single non whitespace character other than `-` as a value for every item

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cLLRwz/1)